# IEnumerable Expression-Bodied Member C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable, c#-6.0, yield-return, c#-7.0

I have a get-only property in C# that returns an `IEnumerable`.  If that property will only ever yield once, then I could define my property like so:

```
public IEnumerable Derp {
    get { yield return new SomeObject(); }
}
```

But how would I do this with a C#6 expression-bodied member?  The following approaches do ***NOT*** work:

```
// These definitions do NOT work
public IEnumerable Derp => yield return new SomeObject();
public IEnumerable Derp => yield new SomeObject();
```

returning compiler error CS0103: "The name 'yield' does not exist in the current context".  Is a `yield`ing expression-bodied member even possible in C#6?  How about in C#7?

I'm aware that an IEnumerable member that only returns once looks smelly, but I'm mainly just curious.  I came across this situation while experimenting with the NUnit `TestCaseSource` API, trying to provide a method that yields only one test case.  I could also see this being relevant to Unity developers who want to define an expression-bodied method to be called with StartCoroutine().

Anyway, thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: Why can't you `Derp => new[] { new SomeObject() };`? You don't really need to use the `yield` here

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Expression-bodied functions/properties can't have statements... You can't, for example:

```
static int Test(int x) => if (x > 0) x else 0;
```

or even

```
static int Test(int x) => return x;
```

[yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(v=vs.100).aspx) is a statement... You can't use it :-)

Note that you can:

```
IEnumerable<SomeObject> Derp => new[] { new SomeObject() };
```

From the [Roslyn github page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), [New Language Features in C# 6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6):

> 2.1 Expression bodies on method-like members
>   Methods as well as user-defined operators and conversions can be given an expression body by use of the “lambda arrow”:
>
> The effect is exactly the same as if the methods had had a block body with a single return statement.
>
> For void returning methods – and Task returning async methods – the arrow syntax still applies, but the
>   expression following the arrow must be a statement expression (just as is the rule for lambdas):

So there is an exception for `void` returning methods, but still it only covers calling methods (you can `=> Console.WriteLine("Hello");` but you can't `=> if ()`).

Comment: Interesting.  I knew you couldn't have statements in expression-bodied members, but I didn't know yield counted as a statement!  And wow, +1 for reminding me that void methods can be expression-bodied, I totally thought that this wasn't possible before C#7!

Comment: Btw, I'm pretty sure that the latest Roslyn open-source repository is now [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) on GitHub. :)

Comment: @Rabadash8820 And in [C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) they added the option of `=> throw new Exception()` (but this is more a change in the working of the `throw` keyword, not it is legal to use it after the `??` and the `? :` operators

Comment: If your method or property has only one statement and that statement can be writed as an expression, then you can use Expression-Bodied Function Members.    
int Test(int x) => if (x > 0) x else 0;  // invalid    
int Test(int x) => x > 0 ? x : 0; // OK